# Invalid Reference Version When Visual Studio 2012 Starts

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, gac

I recently added a unit test project to my existing .net website project.  I wrote some unit tests and everything was working fine.  We added in a third party testing suit to our development process, and we were given a reference dll to include in our test project (which I have done).

However, the third party dll requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll version 10.1.0.0, and my test project has version 10.0.0.0.  I switched the version (right-click on the References folder in VS, check a box, uncheck a different box).  Now the test project compiles, and unit tests run.

Next day, when I fired up VS and loaded the project, it wouldn't compile - same error as I had previously with the wrong version of the Unit Test Framework dll.

How can I force the version to be 10.1.0.0?  I've even set Specific Version = True on the reference properties and I've tried setting the target framework to both 4 and 4.5 with no luck.

Comment: In your test project, within an app.config file, try using assembly redirection ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this actually was solved by our vendor - the provided an older version of the dll --> compiled against an older version of .NET.  Solved by having them compile it with .NET 4.5.